# $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-2\pi i wx}dx$ exists for no value of $w$.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

While reading Fourier transform theory, I have a remark that says:

*The Fourier transform does not always exist. For example, the function $f (x) = x^2$ does not admit a Fourier transform because the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-2\pi i wx}dx$ exists for no value of $w$.*

But I found a difficulty in proving it. Any idea please

Comment: In fact, it's trickier than that: it exists in the sense of distributions.

Comment: @Made, it's clear the integral doesn't exist (exist in the sense of yielding a finite value) for real values of $\omega$, right?  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Before you can even write down the symbol $\int_{\Bbb{R}}x^2e^{-2\pi i w x}\,dx$, you need to ensure that the integrand is Lebesgue integrable, i.e that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|x^2e^{-2\pi iwx}|\,dx<\infty$. Unfortunately, this is just not true: $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|x^2e^{-2\pi i wx}|\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}x^2\,dx=\infty$. Hence, the integral doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure, we can regard $f(x)=x^2$ as a tempered distribution via $\langle T_f,\phi\rangle:=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\phi(x)\,dx$, for all Schwartz functions $\phi$. Then, the tempered distribution $T_f$ has a Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(T_f)$, which up to constants is the second distributional derivative of the Dirac delta. But this isn't the same as saying the above Lebesgue integral exists. i.e $f(x)=x^2$ does not belong to $L^1(\Bbb{R})$, so we cannot define a Fourier transform for it using an integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the  definition for the Fourier Transform of a function $f(x)$:
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{- 2\pi i x \xi}\,dx,$$   for any real number $ξ$.

We assume $f(x)$ is an integrable function, Lebesgue-measurable on the real line, and satisfy:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| \, dx < +\infty.$$

If you check for the Lebesgue-measurability of $f(x) = x^2$ you will find it doesn't belong to that class of functions, indeed:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x^2 e^{-2\pi i \omega x}|\ \text{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x^2| \text{d}x = +\infty$$